# Sql sum inside an other sql select

Tags: mysql

I would like to SUM the foglalas_mennyiseg field in the foglalas table.

With the code below, i get this error: Notice: Undefined index: foglalt

What am i doing wrong?

```
$sql =
                "
                    SELECT 

                        rendeles.rendeles_id,
                        rendeles.rendeles_gyarto,
                        rendeles.rendeles_termek,
                        rendeles.rendeles_mennyiseg,
                        rendeles.rendeles_szam,
                        rendeles.rendeles_status,
                        rendeles.rendeles_created,
                        rendeles.rendeles_visszaig,
                        gyarto.gyarto_nev,
                        termek.termek_nev,
                        termek.termek_egyseg,

                        (SELECT SUM(foglalas.foglalas_mennyiseg) AS foglalt FROM foglalas 
                        WHERE foglalas.foglalas_rendeles_id = rendeles.rendeles_id)

                    FROM rendeles 

                    LEFT JOIN gyarto ON rendeles.rendeles_gyarto = gyarto.gyarto_id 
                    LEFT JOIN termek ON rendeles.rendeles_termek = termek.termek_id

                    ORDER BY rendeles_id DESC LIMIT $actual, $row_per_page

                ";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your name after your subquery

```
....
( SELECT SUM(foglalas.foglalas_mennyiseg)
  FROM foglalas 
  WHERE foglalas.foglalas_rendeles_id = rendeles.rendeles_id
) AS foglalt
....
```